# What is the use of @Order annotation in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-security, annotations

I have come across a glance of code which uses `@Order` annotation. I want to know what is the use of this annotation with respect to Spring Security or Spring MVC.

Here is an example:

```
@Order(1)
public class StatelessAuthenticationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

}
```

What happen to the order of above mentioned class if we do not use this annotation?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html.

Comment: regarding Spring Security this could e.g. define the order in which the security filters are applied

Answer (score 92):

It is used for Advice execution precedence.

The highest precedence advice runs first. The lower the number, the higher the precedence. For example, given two pieces of 'before' advice, the one with highest precedence will run first.

Another way of using it is for ordering Autowired collections

```
@Component
@Order(2)
class Toyota extends Car {
    public String getName() {
        return "Toyota";
    }
}

@Component
@Order(1)
class Mazda extends Car {
    public String getName() {
        return "Mazda";
    }
}

@Component
public class Cars {
    @Autowired
    List<Car> cars;

    public void printNames(String [] args) {

        for(Car car : cars) {
            System.out.println(car.getName())
        }
    }
}
```

You can find executable code here: https://github.com/patrikbego/spring-order-demo.git

Hope this clarifies it a little bit further.

**Output:-**

Mazda Toyota

Comment: Can this be used for specifying the order in which different beans should be destroyed?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: With regards to autowiring collections, what would happen if some beans of the collection had an `@Order` and some don't? Will the ones without automatically be "last"?

Comment: I know this is old, but if a Bean does not include an `@Order` while other beans in a collection do, it implicitely has the default value, namely: `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`.

Answer (score 15):

`@Order` Annotations (as well as the `Ordered` interface) implies a specific order, in which the beans will be loaded or prioritized by Spring.

Lower numbers indicate a higher priority. The feature may be used to add beans in a specific order into a collection (ie via `@Autowired`), among other things.

In your specific example the annotation does not change anything in the class itself. Whereever this specific class is used, it is used with the highest priority (since it is set as '1'), probably since additional, but depending information is being added in other classes, ordered at a lower precedence.

Answer (score 9):

`@Order` Annotation specifies the order of loading the bean by spring container. The lower the order(integer), higher is the precedence. So order of 0 will have more precedence than order of 10. Likewise order of -100 will have more precedence than 0.