# Spring initialise test data in order

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-annotations

In my Spring application I am using the annotation `@PostConstruct` to initialise test data when the Spring application starts to run.

I have two classes `CInitialiser` and `PInitialiser` due to the nature of how I have setup the project i need the `PInitialiser` class to run first. The relationship between the two entities is a bidirectional many to many.

I need the `PInitialiser` entity to run first because I need to initlaise the projects to assign them to customers. But it looks like `CInitialiser` is running first. Is there anyway to make the entity `Project` run first?

Here is my code:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    for (Module m : modules) {
        if (enviromentTest) {
            try {
                m.initData();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and each of my classes implements the `Module`:

`public class CInitialiser implements Module`

`public class PInitialiser implements Module`

Comment: try specifying order using `@Order`

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328897/what-is-the-use-of-order-annotation-in-spring

Comment: Got it to work with some searching thanks, I can accept an answer if you declare it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the order in which spring beans are initialized using `@Order` annotation. [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html)
Here are some examples

[What is the use of @Order annotation in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328897/what-is-the-use-of-order-annotation-in-spring)

https://javapapers.com/spring/spring-order-annotation/