# How to make default EntityManager bean come from @Primary EntityManagerFactory in Spring project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, autowired, entitymanager

**Scenario:**

I have an application extending another application and so it has 2 `DataSource` and 2 `EntityManagerFactory` in it. The first `EntityManagerFactory` is created for the original application, and the second one is what is created and used in my extension. The application being extended uses many of its own jars and I am not looking at modifying any of the code in the original application's jars.

**Bean definitions:**

```
@Bean("em1")
@Primary
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "pc1")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("ds1") DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean retVal = super.entityManagerFactory();
    retVal.setDataSource(myDataSource);
    retVal.setJpaProperties(Properties.getJpaProperties());
    return retVal;
}


@Bean(name = "em2")
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "pc2")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("ds2") DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emf.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:persistence/persistence.xml");
    return emf;
}
```

**Issue:**

I can successfully get an `EntityManager` from the second one in my classes by using

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "pc2")
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

However when the original application tries to get an `EntityManager` in one of its libraries by

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager myEntityManager;
```

it throws a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` saying it found 2 beans of type `EntityManager`

**Question:**

How can I make my `@Primary` `EntityManagerFactory` create an `EntityManager` that is also used by default? Or what other solution can I do to fix these conflicting beans without modifying the original application?

Comment: [@Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328897/what-is-the-use-of-order-annotation-in-spring)

Comment: @emotionlessbananas @ Order does not change the error

Comment: Use @Qualifier to obtain respective Entity Manager

Comment: @SwaritAgarwal It's being autowired in the original application's jars. I don't want to have to manage my own version of those jars.

Comment: use @Resource instead of Autowire and give the name of the bean as @Resource(name="em1")

Comment: also I don't see where have you defined emf reference?

Comment: @ankidaemon Good catch. The emf reference was at the class level and I forgot to copy it over. Fixed in code. I'm trying to avoid replacing the @ Autowired as it is in a jar in the original project.

Comment: @primary should be working, if you've already taken care of all builds properly. Also check this out - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/22711

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same issue and resolve it by creating one default EntityManager marked as @Primay @Bean

```
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    public EntityManager sharedEntityManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(emf);
    }
```

I'm using @Bean Qualified as "entityManagerFactory".
The @Primary annotation forces `@Autowired EntityManager em` to use this primary EnityManager.

If I want to use other EntityManager i can use @Qulifier annotation like this: `@Autowired @Qualifier("entityManagerBeanNumberTwo") EntityManager em`

SharedEntityManagerCreator: `Delegate for creating a shareable JPA EntityManager reference for a given EntityManagerFactory`
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/SharedEntityManagerCreator.html

Full config:

```
@Primary
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = {"my.package.domain"},
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager"
)
@Profile({"test", "default"})
public class TestDatabaseConfiguration {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                       @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("my.package.domain")
            // with this you can make proxy injection by @PersistenceContext(unitName="domain")
            .persistenceUnit("domain")
            .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") @Autowired EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    public EntityManager sharedEntityManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(emf);
    }
}
```

Oryginal answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77070851/9950085
And info from spring team member:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/15076#issuecomment-1634307435